# Dialogflow Facebook Integration is not responding to incoming messages to pages

Tags: facebook, dialogflow-es, chatbot, facebook-apps, dialogflow-es-fulfillment

I have a Facebook messenger bot. This bot is connected to Dialogflow using a Gmail address. I have generated a token from the Facebook app. Then this token is inserted into the Dialogflow account. Also, webhook URL and `verify_token` from Dialogflow are given in the Facebook app.

Now I am facing a very odd problem. The problem is the bot is not responding to page messages or quick replies. So where is the problem? It is Facebook or Dialogflow? Please help me.

I have followed this documentation from Dialogflow. [Dialogflow documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/integrations/facebook) Also, I have followed this tutorial [from youtube.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6T7IFGf0ls)

Comment: Can you provide details if there is any log information or error, if exists? Also can you share some code or purely following the tutorial from the youtube video??

Comment: I was able to replicate the video tutorial and I was able to get a response from the dialogflow. I will post my findings.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to replicate the video tutorial. I think you should be careful with these points.

- On `dialogflow`, check if messenger integration is up and running and its pointing to your working enviroment. Defaults `draft`.
- On `facebook app`, check if its valid and working. Your app must exists and the webhooks should be selected and token should have not changed.
- If token was regenerated you might have to restart the syncronization process as described in the [video you share](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z6T7IFGf0ls).
- Your bot should have basic intents. without intents, you will not get any response.
- Your `intents` should be able to parse your incoming messages else you will not get any response.
- On `dialogflow`, you can check if your intents are working properly by chatting with it. You should get details of the response generated.
  *Hint: You can chat with your dialogflow agent by writing messages on the `Try it now` to see if its working properly*
- Check if `fulfillment` is being use. If so, check if your inline editor or webhook are working properly and returning messages.
- if there is a delay in the response and you are using code behind it you might need to know that response should not exceed the appropriate quotas per minute. For quota details you can see this [link](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/quotas#es-agent).